# Using 2 $count in one query

Tags: python, mongodb

I have the following collection:

```
{'user': 'Emma', 'type': 'Apple'}
{'user': 'Emma', 'type': 'Orange'}
{'user': 'Emma', 'type': 'Orange'}
```

I want to get statistics for "Emma", How many records of "apples" and "oranges" there are.

For example the output:

```
{
    'apple': 1,
    'Orange': 1
}
```

It's very simple to do this if I split it into 2 queries. But for efficiency, I want to do it all at once.

I'm wondering if I should use `$facet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` user condition
- `$group` by `type` and get count
- `$group` by null and construct the array of `type` and count in key-value format
- `$arrayToObject` convert above key-value array to object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above converted object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { user: "Emma" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      types: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$count" } }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$types" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i-oBA3X6shO)